# How can i add a button on a div in my tpl inside a dataview?

Tags: html, extjs, render, store, dataview

i have a problem trying to add a button in a tpl. i have this inside a panel. I want to upload a file trough this button. the record its getting in the itemClick listener, and i can edit and save the record in the db, but i want to upload a file with this.

```
items:{
  height: 310,
  bind: '{somestore}',
  id: 'somestore-panel',
  xtype: 'dataview',
  columnWidth: '100',
  tpl: [
   '<tpl for="." >',
     '<div id="upload-button" ></div>',
   '</tpl>'
  ]
  cls: 'div-selection',

  overItemCls: 'over-selection',

  listeners: {
    'itemclick': 'onClickDataButton',
    afterrender:function(){
      var button = new Ext.Button({
        renderTo:'upload-button',
        xtype: 'filefield',
        text:'Vote',
        width:100,
        id:'upload-form',
        handler:function(){
          alert('Vote Button is clicked');
        }
      })
      console.log(button);
   }
 }
}
```

and its returning a

> Cannot read property 'dom' of null

All the store its getting correct and all its fine if i dont use a button, i dont know if there is a better way to add a component.

Comment: I think you are too early in the component lifecycle. I believe Data Views have a refresh event for after an tpl is executed

Comment: my problem was that i was writing bad the id in the div, but the purpose of that button is get something like filefield in the form, but trough the buttom but i cant open the File Explorer trough a button, thats my problem now, because if i create a Ext.form, that isnt render to the template like the button do. In the Ext.form i put a buttonOnly: true. and the other settings but its created but not rendered. how can i render to the tpl?